# How to identify the input that caused a program to segfault?

Tags: bash, scripts, error-handling

I have scripts that run programs (that I did not author) and some are getting segfaults on a few inputs.  I do these things in large batches that run for up to a week, and would like to know which input(s) are triggering the problem.  As it stands, I get a notification from Bash that a certain script of mine has gotten a seg fault.  But the problem is not in the script, it's in the 3rd party program and its input.  If I had the name of the input, I could work on the problem.

The current form of the call in my Bash script is (for example program 'autofix')

```
  for indata in base*.fix; do        
      autofix $indata >${indata/.fix/.stdout} &                                                                                               
  done
```

As you can see, they are started in the background, and on my workhorse server, there may be as many as 100 or so of these started at once, so I cannot tell which one has failed, and I'm not patient enough to try all 100 one at a time,  since each may take an hour.  Capturing stderr does not capture anything so I'm looking for other ideas.

Comment: Wrap your `autofix` command in a `bash` script, and call that script from your `for` loop. In the scrip you can control `autofix`'s outputs, check it's exit status, trap segfaults, etc. Read `man bash`.

Comment: @waltinator can I do that in a {} subscript, or does that need to be a separate file?  And man bash is kinda long and general -- I have not found it useful unless I'm already focused on a particular capability.  Can you suggest what it would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one in-line solution based just by playing with things I already knew (or was at least used to bumping into) in Bash.  To test and to illustrate, I'm using a tiny C program I wrote that just causes a SEGFAULT:

```
// Cause a seg fault

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *zero = 0;
    *zero = 0;
    printf("Hey, how did I get away with this?");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Then after some trials (see comments below) I wound up with this simple pattern in Bash (which could be a one-liner but I'm presenting a more readable form):

```
   if ./segfault
   then
      echo strange success
   else
      echo this died with return code $?
   fi
```

This does not die because of the SEGFAULT, but just notices it. Therefore the output is "this died" and not "strange success" or a total process fault.

This approach shows the error code that distinguishes between SEGFAULT and other forms of process failure, in case that is desired.

Finally, after deciding I needed more information, I came up with a solution in this form (with some details simplified):

```
// expecting input files with names beginning with "input".
// the names become prefixes for the output file names.
for input in input*; do
  dodgy-code ${input} >${input}-stdout 2>${input}-stderr ||
    echo Error in ${input} with code $?  >>error-list
done
// clean up empty report files
for report in *stderr ; do
  if [ -f $report && ! -s $report ] then 
    rm $report
  fi
done

// now there are stdout files for all inputs, stderr files for
// the ones that returned an error code and an "error-list" file
// listing the inputs that caused problems and the error code returned.
```

Comment: That's a very roundabout way of doing `if ! ./segfault > realstdout; then echo this died ...`

Comment: @muru I agree that it's roundabout. But it works which your idea does not -- instead the shell reports the segfault and stops the process.

Comment: Hmm? With your example C code, using my `if`, I get `this died` as expected (in addition to the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` message but that's not relevant to the check itself). If "the shell ... stops the process", which process did it stop?

Comment: @muru You are absolutely right.  I must have been thrown off by the core dumped message and not looked more closely.   My apologies.  Background: some time ago I heard or read "frequently wrong, never in doubt" and I resonated with that.  I try to guard against it, but at 80 years old, changes are hard and slow.  I hope you understand.

Comment: I would just lose the ! (i.e. not) and turn it around to avoid losing the error code:  `if ./segfault > realstdout; then true; else echo this dies with $?; fi `

Comment: Sure, that'll work too, I was aiming to produce the equivalent of your code. So now you can edit your post to have the simpler code in it.

Comment: @muru Done.  Thanks.